# Display the result of a calculation before the calculation

Tags: texlive

I want to perform various calculations in a document, but I want the result of these calculations to be displayed at the beginning of the document.

I have the following approach, but unfortunately the output is always 0.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fp} % Paket für die Berechnungen
\usepackage{etoolbox} % Paket für zusätzliche Befehle wie \AtEndDocument

% Befehl zur Speicherung des Ergebnisses definieren
\newcommand{\result}{0}

\begin{document}

% Das Ergebnis der Berechnung wird hier angezeigt
Das Ergebnis der Berechnung ist: \result

% Weitere Inhalte des Dokuments...
% ...

% Berechnung am Ende des Dokuments durchführen
\AtEndDocument{
  \FPeval{\result}{clip(2*3+4)}
  \global\let\result\result % Das Ergebnis global verfügbar machen
}

\end{document}
```

How can I change the code so that the correct result is displayed? I do not want to use any additional files.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TeX expands macros, so it's impossible for `\result` to expand to something which is defined later in the file. But you can use the `\AtEndDocument` hook (for which you don't need `etoolbox`) to write the value into the `aux` file. That's how labels work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fp} % Paket für die Berechnungen

% Befehl zur Speicherung des Ergebnisses definieren
\newcommand*{\result}{0}

\begin{document}

% Das Ergebnis der Berechnung wird hier angezeigt
Das Ergebnis der Berechnung ist: \result

\makeatletter
% Berechnung am Ende des Dokuments durchführen
\AtEndDocument{%
  \FPeval{\result}{clip(2*3+4)}%
  \write\@auxout{\global\string\def\string\result{\result}}%
}
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

[image]

Clearly you need to run TeX at least twice for the result to be displayed correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the spot-on [answer by Campa](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/713120/4427), I'd add an interface for managing as many variables as you want.

This is tailored for `fp`. At the end of the calculation you save the value giving it a name (in the example `x` and `y`), using the macro you stored the value in (default `\result`).

At the end of the LaTeX run, the collected values are dumped in the aux file so they can be read in at the beginning of the next run.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\prop_new:N \g_hr_variables_out_prop
\prop_new:N \g_hr_variables_in_prop

\NewDocumentCommand{\savevariable}{O{\result}m}
 {
  \prop_gput:Nne \g_hr_variables_out_prop { #2 } { #1 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\printvariable}{m}
 {
  \prop_item:Nn \g_hr_variables_in_prop { #1 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\VARIABLES}{m}
 {
  \prop_gset_from_keyval:Nn \g_hr_variables_in_prop { #1 }
 }

\AtEndDocument
 {% dump the variables in the aux file
  \iow_shipout:ce { @mainaux }
   {
    \VARIABLES
     {
      \prop_map_function:NN \g_hr_variables_out_prop \__hr_variables_dump:nn
     }
   }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \__hr_variables_dump:nn { #1=#2, }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Variable $x$ is $\printvariable{x}$.

Variable $y$ is $\printvariable{y}$.

\section{Main}

We set a variable to \FPadd{\result}{2}{2}\savevariable{x}\result

We set another variable to \FPmul{\y}{2}{3}\savevariable[\y]{y}\y

\end{document}
```

At the end of the run the aux file will have

```
\VARIABLES {
x=4.000000000000000000,
y=6.000000000000000000,
}
```

This obviously requires two runs when the variables change.

[image]